# How to scatter dots in the dotplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Good day, I have a problem with a dotplot. It's not look in the right way, dots are lined up, and they should be scattered. How can I do this in the right way?

That's what I was doing.

> `Plot_AM44_length <- ggplot(AM44_1_5_red, aes(x=Worm_Names, y=Length))+ geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", stackratio = 1, dotsize = 0.3, position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0.1))`

And It`s looks like this. How can I change in plot place of the dots?
[image]

It must be like in this plot
[image]

Comment: Hi Lina. The dots aren't spread out like in the lower plots, because in the lower plot you are plotting two _numerical_ variables against each other. In the top plot, you have one categorical variable and one numerical variable. There are therefore only two distinct x-values that a dot can have - "1 red" or "5 red", and all the dots need to line up above them because otherwise, what would the x-value of the dots represent? The usual way to show this kind of data is with a boxplot, not with a scatterplot / dotplot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don`t understand why I can`t do a plot like a lower plot. I know that it`s different kinds of data, but the top plot doesn`t show the data in the right way. It`s can`t be dots in the same place, each dot have different  value in the y axis!

Comment: yes - and in the top plot, the dots _do_ all have different y axis values (they are scattered up and down vertically). But there are only two unique values for x, so the plot is putting them there. For example, try running the line ` plot(rep(1:2, 10), rnorm(20))`. There are only two unique x values, so there are two vertical lines of dots in this plot. Compare it to `plot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))`, where the dots are spread out across the x axis. This is because there are 100 unique values of x. The dots are only being plotted where you are telling R to plot them.

Comment: The fact that your x axis is called "worm names" means that you are plotting all the y values for each unique worm name, which is a categorical variable. If you had a point that was halfway between the two worm names on the x axis, which worm would it refer to?

Comment: Oh, it`s okey I found my mistake, I did not use a binwidth!

Comment: @AllanCameron thank you for help!